# Setting state (coming from parent comp) in recursive react component without resetting the component?

Tags: reactjs, recursion, state

data source: https://api.jsonserve.com/wIkGmS

```
function Family({
    familyTree,
    onUpdate,
}: {
    familyTree;
    onUpdate?: (item) => void;
}) {
    const [localIsVisible, setLocalIsVisible] = useState(false);
    const expand = () => {
        setLocalIsVisible(!localIsVisible);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        onUpdate && onUpdate(localIsVisible);
    }, [localIsVisible]);

    return (
        <div style={{ paddingLeft: 10 }}>
            <span onClick={expand}>{familyTree.name}</span>
            {localIsVisible ? (
                familyTree?.children?.map((child) => {
                    return (
                        <div style={{ paddingLeft: 10 }}>
                            <Family familyTree={child} />
                        </div>
                    );
                })
            ) : (
                <></>
            )}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Parent component:

```
  const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = useState(false);

 ....
 return (
  ....
  <Family
                familyTree={familyTree}
                onUpdate={(item) => setIsVisible(item)}
            />
   .... )
```

The problem is that if the **onUpdate** sets the state - as shown above - in the parent component, the **<Family .. />** component resets to initial state

If I just console log it out, thats fine

Can I set the **IsVisible state** somehow in the parent component (coming from the child component) that doesnt make the child component reset back to default ?

Comment: You can directly call onUpdate(localIsVisible) inside expand function.

Comment: Its very important for me that the state is coming from and saved in the parent, I have to have it there

Answer (score 0):

We can make quick work of this using **mutual recursion**.

Here's a minimal, verifiable example of a recursive type and corresponding React component. Notice -

- `List` builds zero or more `ListItem` components
- `ListItem` optionally builds a `List`

<kbd>Run</kbd> the demo below and watch the list items shuffle around, simulating state change in the recursive structure. Note that each child maintains its own open/close state, regardless of the parent tree state changes.

How does it work? After you read the [**Preserving and Resetting State guide**](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/preserving-and-resetting-state) from the React docs, you will understand the **critical role** of the `key` property. In this demo we use the `item.title` to "link" the data to reach corresponding node. On subsequent renders, React uses this property to know whether you are rendering a new node, or re-rendering an existing one.

```js
function List({ initialItems = [] }) {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState(initialItems)
  React.useEffect(() => {
    // carousel effect to simulate changing state of list
    const t = setTimeout(() => {
      setState(([first, ...more]) => [...more, first])
    }, 2000)
    return () => { clearTimeout(t) }
  })
  return <ul>
    {state.map(item => <ListItem key={item.title} {...item} />)}
  </ul>
}

function ListItem({ title, sublist = [] }) {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false)
  const onClick = e => { e.stopPropagation(); setOpen(!open) }
  return <li onClick={onClick}>
    {open || sublist.length == 0 ? "➖" : "➕"}
    {title}
    {open && <List initialItems={sublist} />}
  </li>
}

const menu = [
  { title: "Clothing", sublist: [ { title: "Athletics" }, { title: "Formal" }, { title: "Casual" } ] },
  { title: "Electronics", sublist: [ { title: "Computers" }, { title: "Mobile Phones", sublist: [ { title: "Apple" }, { title: "Android" } ] } ] }
]
        
ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector("#app")).render(
  <List initialItems={menu} />
)
```

```css
li { list-style-type: none; }
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Using `event.stopPropagation()` ensures only the clicked item will toggle, and not the item's ancestors.

As expected, the types are mutually recursive too -

```
type tlist = Array<tlistitem>

type tlistitem = {
  title: string,
  sublist?: tlist
}
```

```
function List(props: { initialItems: tlist }) // ...
function ListItem(props: tlistitem) // ...
```

If you enjoyed this, you can read my [other answers about mutual recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A633183+mutual+recursion) to learn more ways to apply the technique.

**state in parent component**

In a follow-up you ask to keep the state in a component that is parent to the tree. We can use a single `Map` in the the parent that keeps track of a node's visibility based on the node's unique id. `isOpen` and `toggle` functions are passed down as props to the children -

```js
function App({ items = [] }) {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(() => new Map())
  const isOpen = item => open.get(item.id) || false
  const toggle = item => setOpen(m => new Map(m).set(item.id, !isOpen(item)))
  return <List items={items} isOpen={isOpen} toggle={toggle} />
}

function List({ items, isOpen, toggle }) {
  return <ul>
    {items.map(item => <ListItem key={item.id} item={item} isOpen={isOpen} toggle={toggle} />)}
  </ul>
}

function ListItem({ item, isOpen, toggle }) {
  const { id, sublist = [] } = item
  const onClick = e => { e.stopPropagation(); toggle(item) }
  return <li onClick={onClick}>
    {isOpen(item) || sublist.length == 0 ? "➖" : "➕"}
    {id}
    {isOpen(item) && <List items={sublist} isOpen={isOpen} toggle={toggle} />}
  </li>
}

const menu = [
  { id: "Clothing", sublist: [ { id: "Athletics" }, { id: "Formal" }, { id: "Casual" } ] },
  { id: "Electronics", sublist: [ { id: "Computers" }, { id: "Mobile Phones", sublist: [ { id: "Apple" }, { id: "Android" } ] } ] }
]
        
ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector("#app")).render(
  <App items={menu} />
)
```

```css
li { list-style-type: none; }
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

In the example above, we have a *list* of root nodes. If your app only has a *single* root, you can wrap the initial input in a singleton array -

```
function App({ tree }) {
  // ...
  return <List items={[tree]} isOpen={isOpen} toggle={toggle} />
}

// single node
const root = { id: "Electronics", sublist: [ { id: "Computers" }, { id: "Mobile Phones", sublist: [ { id: "Apple" }, { id: "Android" } ] } ] }
        
ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector("#app")).render(
  <App tree={root} />
)
```

Comment: You're holding the state in the recursive component, which is not something I want, cause I wanna work with it in the parent component, if I do set it in the parent component, it resets the whole recursive component, if I set it in the recursive component, I cant utilize it in the parent WHICH IS MY GOAL. Do you think there is a way to do that?

Comment: sure i'll make an update later today

Comment: how is it going, any updates?

Comment: @LeventeBognár thanks for pinging me, I made a quick update for you :D

Comment: Thanks, it works cool. I wonder why I cant make it work by simply using a very simple state setter "string" based instead of a "map" based state like you did here. With my idea it always resets on component state set, but with your solution it doesnt, is it the callback that does the job?